# Claims based authentication from Asp.NET to SharePoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, sharepoint-2013, claims-based-identity, claims

I have an Asp.NET MVC application and a SharePoint web application. Users inside the asp.net application needs to get/display data from a SharePoint site (or click links to go to the SharePoint Site) without the need to authenticate on SharePoint as the authentication is already done on the Asp.Net site using FBA.

When users once login to the MVC application, they need to get a Security Token (containing Claims) from a Identity Provider and pass it on to the SharePoint Application, when they want to see their data from SP or click on a sp link. Am I right?

Is it possible to achive this solution? appreciate all kind of advice.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749937/single-sign-on-between-sharepoint-2010-web-application-and-asp-net-mvc-web-appli